# Why is Windows shows my 16 GB Memory Stick Pro Duo as 126 GB?

Tags: memory-card

I try to revive my PSP after 4 years of not touching it. Charged it to 100%, every components work as intended except the Memory Stick reader or the MemStick itself.

1. It states that I have to format.
2. After trying to format with PSP formatter, it states `Format failed. Error (80220087)`
3. I connect my PSP with USB cable with MemStick inside the PSP, my Windows shows it has 126 GB instead of actual 16 GB.
4. I download `guiformat` from RidgeCrop and format my memstick. Once it reach 99%, it throws error `Failed to set volume label, GetLastError()=1005. The volume does not contain a recognized file system`.
5. Tried `chkdsk` but it throws error `chkdsk does not work with RAW filesystem`
6. Tried `diskpart` but cannot `select partition 1`. Cannot even `create partition primary`, it throws `Insufficient unused space ...`
7. Downloaded `HPUSBDisk.exe` and tried it, it throws `Device Media is write protected`.
8. Downloaded `Panasonic SD Card Formatter` and tried it, it throws `Formatting failed` at 96%.

I do not know what else to try.

**Update:**

Step 8 produced a log file, at the end of the log file it wrote

`PROGRESS:96/100 Creating SD-compatible partition table...
PROGRESS:100/100 Creating SD-compatible partition table...
[ERROR] Invalid end of sector signature: 0x678F
[ERROR] exfat_check_validate_boot_sector returned error: 22 (Invalid argument)
[ERROR] Initializing cached values failed: 22 (Invalid argument)
[ERROR] Generated invalid volume. exfat_volume_create returned: 22 (Invalid argument)`

Comment: If `diskpart`'s `clean` doesn't work you might just have to accept that the stick has failed.

Comment: @Bob `diskpart clean` works, but the rest of the command does not :(

Comment: Your stick is defective, gone... Get another.